# On click dropdown in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem in Bootstrap. I have one dropdown list, but when I click on that dropdown list, the colors are changed to gray. I am trying to make class `dropdown` visited black (because my `navbar` is black) but it does not work.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="properties.php?type=showall" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-language" style="color:white;"></i>
     Language
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="propertiesSearch.php">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="propertiesSearch.php">Bosanski</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change these to black (or hex color to match your bar):

```
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: black;
```

}

```
.nav .open > a,
.nav .open > a:hover,
.nav .open > a:focus {
    background-color: black;
    border-color: #428bca;
```

}